# How to group MySQL results based on field

Tags: php, mysql

Hi, I have a table called msgsubjects with a schema shown below. Basically it holds messages for users. The field viewstatus is used to show if a message has been read/not. if its 0, msg is unread and 1 if message has been viewed.

```
id  int(11)         No      auto_increment                          
    ownerid int(11)         No                                  
    posterid    int(11)         No                                  
    viewstatus  int(11)         No                                  
    bodyid  int(11)         No                                  
    subject varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci     No                                   
    date    int(11)
```

This is my current sql to pull these results.

```
$q=sprintf("SELECT * FROM msgsubjects WHERE ownerid=%d ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT %d,%d",$curid,$start,$end);
```

Want I want to do is have my results returned grouped having unread messages shown first regardless, I want the groups to still be ordered by date. Can this be done with sql?  I know I can do this with php but sql would be more efficient.

Comment: You could use `TINYINT` (1 byte) instead of `INT` (4 bytes) for the `viewstatus`. Or even `BIT` (1 bit). And `DATE` type for the `"date"`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/data-types.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wanting to sort the messages by the `viewstatus` column

```
$q=sprintf("SELECT * FROM msgsubjects WHERE ownerid=%d ORDER BY viewstatus ASC, date DESC LIMIT %d,%d",$curid,$start,$end);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it is a very simple solution to the problem.

`ORDER BY` accepts multiple fields so that you can sort using more than one column.

```
ORDER BY viewstatus ASC, date DESC
```

---

Link to documentation regarding sorting in MySQL:

- [MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 3.3.4.4 Sorting Rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)